# Loading a file from disk, loads a few extra characters

Tags: c, opengl, file-io

This program recieves a pointer to a const char* data type, loads a text file from disk into memory, and passes the address of the first index of the resulting char[] back (essentially passes the contents of the file back as a 'string').

This works just fine, though it *sometimes* passes back a few extra characters with the file contents.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* loadShaders(char* PATH) {

    FILE *fp = fopen(PATH, "rb");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("[ctb.h] loadShaders() ");
        printf("[ctb.h] loadShaders() recieved file path: %s\n", PATH);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    char* shader = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(shader, fsize, 1, fp);
    shader[fsize + 1] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    return shader;
}
```

When it does pass extra characters back, the result looks something like this:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}�
```

As you may have guessed, the "�" does not belong.

Suggestions?

Comment: Don't you mean: `shader[fsize] = '\0';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line causes undefined behavior by writing off the end of an array:

```
shader[fsize + 1] = '\0';
```

Simple to fix:

```
shader[fsize] = '\0';
```